# addReplyTo doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, apache-commons

everyone.

I'm trying to configure a email specifying an email address to reply to using the [addReplyTo method](http://commons.apache.org/email/api-1.0/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#addReplyTo%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and although the email is sent successfully
[image]

when I log into the email account(**octunprg@gmail.com**) to read and reply to the email that has just been sent, the email address that appears in the **To** field is the same email address (**octunprg@gmail.com**) not the one I indicated using "addReplyTo"(**eddysmith1818@gmail.com**) when I set the email.

Is it the normal operation?? Am I doing something wrong??

[image]

```
            Email email = new SimpleEmail();
            email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
            email.setSmtpPort(587);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("octunprg@gmail.com", "123456"));
            email.setTLS(true);
            email.setFrom(from, name);// 'eddysmith1818@gmail.com', 'Eddy Smith'
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setMsg(message);
            email.addReplyTo(from, name);   // 'eddysmith1818@gmail.com', 'Eddy Smith'             
            email.addTo("octunprg@gmail.com");
            email.send();
```

Comment: I hope for your sake those email addresses are fake :D

Answer (score 0):

This may be a mistake in your email client (Gmail, as I see).

Comment: Use the `show details` link on the email to see if the `reply-to` header is listed there.

Comment: @Stephen - yes the reply-to header is listed, take a look at the fist screenshot

Comment: @eddy - which suggests that your code is correctly setting it, but the Gmail UI is ignoring it. You should try sending to some addresses other than gmail, and/or use a client such as Thunderbird to attach to your gmail account as an IMAP client.

Comment: @Stephen -I finally opted for the easiest option,changed to hotmail smtp server XD :  `SMTP server: smtp.live.com` , `SMTP Port: 587 (SSL or TSL encryption)`

Comment: This seems to be  a flaw in Gmail, apparently by design :(